# Default/Common Ribbon Icons

Tags: icons, ribbon

I'm starting in WPF Ribbon development and it is very nice!

My problem is to find (FREE) basic icons (like file save/open/etc, cut/paste/etc).

Have you got some suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked at the [Visual Studio Icon Library](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35825)?  Provided you're not using Visual Studio Express, the library should be available as part of the install (if you didn't do a complete install).  The images are free to use from a licensing perspective, provided they are used in a consistent way with the usage listed in the Readme.html file in the same folder as the image (See [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/tips-and-tricks-visual-studio-2010-image-library/) for further information).  Basically as long as you don't use the disk image that's typically associated with "Save" to mean "Open" or some other weird usage, you should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

Update 5 years later: the icon library is now available online.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35825

Answer (score 1):

http://www.famfamfam.com/

Answer (score 1):

Check out the free icons on glyfx.com: http://www.glyfx.com/products/free_vista_ce.html